# OpenOffice bullets and numbering: moving subpoints of line without a number

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'm trying to create a numbered section in OpenOffice writer using the bullets and numbering feature like so:

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
   Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
       3. Sub-line 3
```

where Lines 2, 3 and 4 have been created by clicking "Insert Unnumbered Entry". I can do this, but I want to also be able to place the cursor on Line 4 and click "Move Up with Subpoints" to move Line 4 and all it's sub-lines to above Line 3, like so:

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
       3. Sub-line 3
   Line 3
```

I'm not sure if this is a feature because it doesn't work. Clicking "Move Up with Subpoints" while the cursor is on Line 4 does nothing at all.

However, I've discovered that if instead of creating Line 4 as unnumbered, I create it by simply hitting enter:

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
2. Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
       3. Sub-line 3
```

and then I click "Move Up with Subpoints", I get:

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
2. Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
       3. Sub-line 3
   Line 3
```

which is essentially what I want, except without the "2." in front of "Line 4". Is there a way to get what I want without the number prefacing Line 4?

Answer (score 0):

A test of LibreOffice (version 5.2) finds that, like Apache OpenOffice, it has the same "Move Up with Subpoints" issue.

However, in LO, and likely also in AOO, you can get the result you're looking for by drag & drop. First, select the lines to move, including the paragraph break on the preceding line (i.e. the text show between triple slashes in the following)...

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3///¶
   Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
       3. Sub-line 3///
```

Then, drag & drop the selected text up to the end of 'Line 2'. The result should be...

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
2. Sub-line 3
   Line 3
```

Finally, click just before the 'S' at the start of 'Sub-line 3' and hit Tab twice. The result should be what you're looking for...

```
1. Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 4:
       1. Sub-line 1
       2. Sub-line 2
       3. Sub-line 3
   Line 3
```